# Programmatically extract SQLite .db file from app and bundle it in the same app via Gradle

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gradle, robolectric

I am in a bit of a pickle. My `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate()` method takes too long (60+ seconds). To fix this, I need to bundle an already created .db file as an asset. Unfortunately, I have too many Android dependencies in my `onCreate()` method (Content Values, etc), so I cannot create my `.db` file on its own without emulating Android.

Here's my plan - create two different `SQLiteOpenHelper`s - one for the initial database creation that will generate a `.db` file, and the second `openHelper` to consume that file. Every end user of my app will only ever use the second `openHelper`, but my Gradle build script will use the first `openHelper`.

What type of Gradle logic could be used to accomplish this? The steps would be:

1. run the first `SQLiteOpenHelper` to capture the `.db` file (maybe use Roblectric to run the `onCreate()` on the JVM)
2. copy the `.db` file to my apps `/assets` directory
3. Rebuild my app a final time with the newly generated `.db` file

Is Gradle even capable of solving something like this?

- Note: I know that this is bad design and I am in circular dependency hell. If I was allowed the time (I am not), I would build the initial `.db` file as a separate submodule.
- Note2: Ultimately, I would like to be able to build my app with `./gradlew clean build`

Comment: Can you please explain what "Unfortunately, I have too many Android dependencies in my onCreate() method (Content Values, etc), so I cannot create my .db file on its own without emulating Android." means?

Comment: Why not just use a service, and create the database in the background, finally freeing a flag to let access to the database once created?

Comment: I am using a background service, but I don't want the user to be unable to access use the data for 60+ seconds while the database initializes. Hence, the DB file needs to be included initially

Comment: Post your insertion code, I am guessing we can be extremely optimized: 60 seconds is a really, long time.

Comment: Each one of my tables is represented by a Java class. This java class uses a `ContentValues` builder to update or insert into the appropriate table in the database. My `SQLiteOpenHelper` uses these Java classes for a bunch of inserting. Those same classes are also reused to update their table's data when the app is in use.

Comment: You could show a progress dialog while the database is being initialized, and by that showing the user something is going on, effectively blocking access, and still keep him on the good side while in background your database is created. And may be it's possible to optimize the code that's actually creating the DB so it finishes faster. That still blocks the user but would solve your issue of database pre-packaging, which actually sounds rather hacky to me.

Comment: I can't post it the code, but it basically parses through a LOT of files, reads the content of some of them, and builds a database out of their data. There are foreign keys and unique indexes everywhere

Comment: @Mjoellnir your suggestion is what I am hoping to avoid, but thank you. I also need the .db file for my testing. Having to constantly drop and and recreate the DB for every Test Class is very inefficient. I need to find a way to optimize my tests in that regard

Comment: Well, if you cannot post even the most important code snippets, we can hardly properly help you...

Comment: @Mjoellnir I understand, but help on improving my insertion logic isn't what I am looking for. I want to somehow call my `openHelper`'s `onCreate()` method from my gradle buildscript in order to capture a `.db` file - which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: I am not sure, if it is really possible, since you do not just want a different build, which would indicate to go for _flavors_, but you want to actually _execute_ parts of the _built_ code, like in a test, but not as a test. Robolectric mocks and fakes a lot, so I guess it won't be of much help here, but you could give it a shot, and try building your database with it, and place it into the assets folder before packaging. I am not sure, however, how a hook like that could be realized. Plus, I really would advise against it, as it is ["code smell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Just add a pong game while the database loads.

Comment: What ORM dependency do you use? I would not couple db creation with normal build but I would make another project that is depended on your model classes and capable to create SQLite db from it on jvm